# How can I use python to prints a series of strings mean ± std

Tags: python

I want to print mean ± std in Python.

For instance:

```
 print('30', u"\u00B1", "1")
```

I get

```
 30 ± 1
```

But if I have sevel means and stds, for instance:

```
means = [20, 30 15]
stds = [7, 10, 2]
```

How can I get

```
'20 ± 7'
'30 ± 10'
'15 ± 2'
```

Comment: Use `zip` --> `for m, s in zip(means, stds) : print(m u"\u00B1", s)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that like so:

```
means = [20, 30, 15]
stds = [7, 10, 2]


for mean, std in zip(means, stds):
    x  = f"{mean} ± {std}" #x is a string
    print(x)
```

Comment: how to export the result into a string? Thanks.

Comment: I've edited my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt help. I want to use x as a label in a plot. If I print x out of the for loop, I only get one element.

Comment: Then, you can save `x` in a `list`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand it now.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```py
means = [20, 30, 15]
stds = [7, 10, 2]

for i in zip(means, stds):
    print(i[0], u"\u00B1", i[1])
```